# $injector:unpr Uknown provider -> don't find why it's failing

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the following error:

> angular.js:14199 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: complianceServiceProvider <- complianceService <- ComplianceController

in the following `Controller`:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('tasksModule')
     .controller('ComplianceController', ComplianceController)

     function ComplianceController($log, configService, scheduleService, dateTimeService, storeService,
            areaService, complianceService) {

      ..... some code here

    }
})();
```

And the following `Service`:

```
(function(){
   angular.module('tasksModule')
    .service('complianceService', ComplianceService)

   function ComplianceService($log, $tasksApi) {
      var vm = this

      vm.get = get

      function get(filter){
        $log.debug('Service - ComplianceService - get')

        return $tasksApi
           .then(function(v){
              return v.$request().$get('compliance', filter)
           })
          .then(Compliance)
      }

      function Compliance(resource) {
        return {
          resource : resource,
          tasks : resource.tasks
        }
      }
   }   
})
```

But I'm getting that `injector` error dunno why... Can anybody help me?

Comment: Probably the file which contains your ComplianceService was not properly loaded. To confirm, try moving the whole service declaration to the same file as your controller.

Comment: Only to try I moved it on the same file as my controller and it worked, but I would like to have it on a separate file... what I'm doing wrong while moving it to an external file?

Comment: How are your loading your javascript files? If you are not using any lazy loader just include the javascript file in your index.html

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the function:

```
(function(){
   angular.module('tasksModule')
    .service('complianceService', ComplianceService)

   function ComplianceService($log, $tasksApi) {
      var vm = this

      vm.get = get

      function get(filter){
        $log.debug('Service - ComplianceService - get')

        return $tasksApi
           .then(function(v){
              return v.$request().$get('compliance', filter)
           })
          .then(Compliance)
      }

      function Compliance(resource) {
        return {
          resource : resource,
          tasks : resource.tasks
        }
      }
   }   
̶}̶)̶
//IMPORTANT - Invoke the function
})()
```

It is important to invoke the function.

For more information, see

- [Wikipedia - Immediately-invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)